# SSRS Expression for Cell backgound color based on cell to the left

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a field expression for a Cells in my report where I have to change the background color of the cell depending on the value in the cell to the left. Ex: if the cell to the left does not have the same vaule in it, the cell should show a red background color.

I tried the following:
`=IIF(Fields!cell.Value, cell.left "value", "Red")`

Image for the example is this,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a way to refer to certain cells within a table in SSRS.

I think the best way to do this would be to use the same expression that you are using the two cells in your comparison for the **Background Color** expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!Lot_QTY.Value = Fields!Allocated_QTY.Value, "White", "Red")
```

Your data might be using a SUM:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Lot_QTY.Value) = SUM(Fields!Allocated_QTY.Value), "White", "Red")
```

The only issue is if you are using a matrix for the data but that doesn't seem likely given your data.

The text box Expression is where you put the value to display in the cell. The properties are used to control things like the BackgroundColor, Font Color, Font Weight, cell border color...

[image]

Comment: Does the placement of the expression matter? as the only thing happening when i run it report is the word "White" at the location the expression has been placed. 
Screenshots below
http://imgur.com/a/yEPld

Comment: It sounds like you are putting the expression in the text box's **expression** rather than the **BackgroundColor** property. I added a pic to see where the Background property is. The expression is used to show the value while the Background color property determines what the color of the cell is.

Comment: Thank you for the visual this has been solved.

thanks again.